# How do we use show and show up?

Tags: word-usage

I am quite confused as to when to use the words show and show up.

I have been thinking show is an action conducted by a person, and show up is used

when someone appeared, like "He has been showing up recently in the party."

However, I have seen someone saying "an error message keeps showing up", and became confused since then because I have been using the expression "an error message keeps showing"

I've become curious about the exact usage of those words in different situations.

Which word do I have to choose in that situation?

Is it "an error showing up" or "an error showing" ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just edited my question to eliminate any confusion you may have.

Comment: What research have you done? What makes you believe that "show up" means that *a **person*** has appeared?  Doesn't it make sense to say that an error message appeared?

Comment: The denotation of the phrasal verb "show up" is to be conspicuous or clearly visible. I was wondering which one is correct, "an error showing up" or "an error showing". I have heard both of them, so I would like to be aware of if I can use both of them or there's a particular expression I should use to be grammatically appropriate.